# Groovy Java cross compilation instanceof

Tags: java, groovy, casting, instanceof

I'm looking a way to check from Java, that some object is an instance of some Groovy class.

It's looks like it's impossible, due to compilation process, including Java class stubs generation, for each Groovy class. So, instanceof with Groovy class will return false.

In Watches window I can test it.

```
ModelNode.class = {java.lang.Class@4830}"class ModelNode"
component.getClass() = {java.lang.Class@3073}"class ModelNode"
component instanceof ModelNode = false
```

Obviously, there are **two different classes**. And Java see generated one. So, I'm looking a nice way to check some object against Groovy class.

I'v tried reflexion and getSuperclass() method, and it's looks like there are two absolutely different classes, derived from same superclass.

```
component.getClass().getSuperclass() = {java.lang.Class@871}"class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode"
ModelNode.class.getSuperclass() = {java.lang.Class@871}"class javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode"
```

Moreover **I can't cast** anything after instanceof, due to similar reasons. So, I must be doing smth **wrong**.

Is there a way to use Groovy objects in Java. Without having Java-side interface for ech necessary from java code method.

P.S. Last sentence is about such solution.

In Java

```
interface A {
  foo();
}

assert(object instanceof B) // false;
((A)object).foo(); // fail
assert(object instanceof A) // true;
((A)object).foo(); // nice
```

In Groovy

```
class B extends SMTH implements A { ... }
```

Comment: On a second thought, are you using eclipse?

Comment: @Will No, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA CE 12.1.4, with groovy 2.1.3 and 1.6 JDK. MacBook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof GroovyObject`?

I created the following Java class:

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;

public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    if (b instanceof GroovyObject) {
      System.out.println("b is a groovyobject");
      b.yeah();
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException("b is not a groovyobject");
    }
  }
}
```

And the following Groovy class:

```
class B {
  def yeah() {
    println "hell yeah"
  }
}
```

With the following result:

```
$ javac -cp ~/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar:. A.java 
$ java -cp ~/groovy/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.3.jar:. A
b is a groovyobject
hell yeah
```

Comment: Oh It's looks interesting.
If I create an Groovy object on Java side, I will get same results, as yours. All will work properly.
If I create object on Groovy side, then pass it to Java code to check it's class, I will get results from my post.
**node** is ModelNode object created on Java side.

`node.getClass() = {java.lang.Class@3137}"class ModelNode"`;
`ModelNode.class = {java.lang.Class@3137}"class ModelNode"`;
`component.getClass() = {java.lang.Class@3099}"class ModelNode"`;
`node instanceof ModelNode = true`;